# PHP 5.5.38 Trying To Install ZipArchive from PECL

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php

I'm attempting to install ZipArchive for PHP 5.5.38 and having a little trouble

`sudo pecl install zip` grabs the source and then I get...

```
running: phpize
sh: 1: phpize: not found
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Everything that I find on installing phpize leads me to `sudo apt-get install php5-dev` which installs PHP 5.6

I cannot seem to find a resource anywhere regarding PHP 5.5 and phpize

Unfortunately, upgrading to 5.6 isn't an option at the moment and my client certainly doesn't want to hear that I can't zip his files because I can't install ZipArchive.

Any thoughts on getting ZipArchive installed on PHP 5.5 and/or phpize would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I ended up using a 3rd party library for this but using built in functions is always my preference. Feel free to leave suggestions of course